# EM_LIMITTEXTの制限が突破された問題

Tags: c++, windows

以下の2つの場合で、EM_LIMITTEXTの制限が突破できると思います、何か改善の方法ご存じでしょうか。

１．すでに入力制限に達した状態で、ENTERキーを押すと、まだ改行を入力できる
２．ATOKというソフト導入のDesktop端末で、以下の設定をして、すでに入力制限に達した状態でも、まだテンキーから数字を自由(※)に入力できる。

設定：「ATOKプロパティ→入力・変換タブ→入力補助→テンキーからの入力を必ず半角にする(T)を選択する

※自由といっても、上限が256バイトの場合、さらに256バイト入力できるようです。

特にNO.2について、現場ユーザーの設定は自分の好みあるので、ATOK設定変更なしで、EM_LIMITTEXTの制限を突破できないようにしたいです。

Comment: [`EM_LIMITTEXT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-limittext)はバイト数でなく文字数なのは把握されていますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。この点は把握しています。こちらのアプリはUNICODEではないので、全角文字２BYTE、半角文字１BYTEとなっています。
上限は256バイトとなっており、全角文字128文字を入力して、さらに入力できない状態で、キーボード右側のテンキー部分で入力ができ(ATOKの設定により、全角モードでも半角数字が入力されている)、キーボード上部の数字だと、全角数字となっていて、入力できない状態でした。

Comment: 把握されているのであれば、質問文を適切に修正してください。また読み込んでいるCommon Controlのバージョン依存の挙動ですので、バージョンも記載してください（確認方法も含めて）。ATOKに拘られているようですが、他のIMEの挙動も併記してください。ATOK固有の問題であれば、製作元に問い合わせるべきとも思います。

Answer (score 0):

問題２．について
Windows標準IMEで発生しないので、ATOK固有の問題と判断し、開発元に問い合わせます。

saiyuriさん、ありがとうございました。